# Adding LIMIT 1 to COUNT query

Tags: php, mysql

This is a COUNT query I'm using to display pages:

```
$sql = "
SELECT SUM(num) as num FROM (
  SELECT
    COUNT(URL) AS num
    , 'World' AS GoSection
    , 'GW' AS MySite
  FROM gw_geog
  WHERE URL = :MyURL AND G1 = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT
    COUNT(URL) AS num
    , 'World' AS GoSection
    , 'GW' AS MySite
  FROM gw_geog_political
  WHERE URL = :MyURL
 ) AS X";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();
```

I want to make two changes:

1) Delete **WHERE URL = :MyURL** from each line and incorporate it into a single line at the end of the query

2) Zap duplicates by adding **LIMIT 1**

This is what I'm working with right now.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(num) as num FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num, 'World' AS GoSection, 'GW' AS MySite FROM gw_geog WHERE URL = :MyURL AND G1 = 1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num, 'World' AS GoSection, 'GW' AS MySite FROM gw_geog_political WHERE URL = :MyURL
 ) AS X
WHERE X.URL LIKE :MyURL LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':MyURL',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();
```

However, I get the error message **Unknown column X.SUM** (or X.URL, etc.).

Can someone show me the correct way to do this?

Comment: can you clarify "zap duplicates"? to me that means it should only count each distinct URL once, regardless of which table it lives in, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Query As Follows and you will get your desired output:

```
 SELECT
    SUM(num) AS num
FROM
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(URL) AS num,
        'World' AS GoSection,
        'GW' AS MySite,
        gw_geog.`URL` as URL  
    FROM
        gw_geog
    WHERE
        URL = :MyURL
    AND G1 = 1
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
            COUNT(URL) AS num,
            'World' AS GoSection,
            'GW' AS MySite,
             gw_geog_political.`URL` as URL
        FROM
            gw_geog_political
        WHERE
            URL = :MyURL
) AS X
WHERE
    X.URL like  :MyURL
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, `limit 1` is not what you're looking for.

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ffbd/5

```
SELECT count(URL) AS num
    ,'World' AS GoSection
    ,'GW' AS MySite
FROM (
    SELECT URL
        ,G1
        ,'a' AS tbl
    FROM gw_geog

    UNION ALL

    SELECT URL
        ,G1
        ,'b' AS tbl
    FROM gw_geog
    ) a
WHERE a.tbl = 'b'
    OR (
        a.tbl = 'a'
        AND a.G1 = 1
        )
    AND a.URL = :MyURL
```